# File.open, write and save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I am trying to get a .rb file to make another .rb file within a specific directory with specified content, when that file is run. I dont know whether the best way to do this would be with a Ruby file or a Rake file. You input would be great.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This turned out to be the best solution.

```
File.open("linecount.txt",'w') do |filea|
  File.open("testfile.txt",'r') do |fileb|
    while line = fileb.gets
      filea.puts line.length
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Within a rails project - where would you place the linecount.txt file?

Comment: Where should I write this code ? i have same requirement but i dont know where should i write this code and execute this

Answer (score 45):

If you just need to perform a simple script like creating a file, you can simply use a Ruby script without creating a rake task.

```
# file origin.rb
target  = "target.rb"
content = <<-RUBY
  puts "I'm the target!"
RUBY

File.open(target, "w+") do |f|
  f.write(content)
end
```

And you can execute the file with

```
$ ruby origin.rb
```

Comment: I think you can also use puts instead of write

Answer (score 25):

```
directory = "../../directory"
File.open(File.join(directory, 'file.rb'), 'w') do |f|
  f.puts "contents"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dogbert - if I had more complex content, like a few methods with constants which can be placed within a string, how would I go about it.

Comment: What format do you have the content in? How are you getting/generating the content?