# RoR - Upload JSON render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a "Rule list" on "localhost:3000/rules" and its JSON render on "localhost:3000/rules.json"

I want to creat the action "Publish" to upload this json to my FTP but I don't find the solution to make this with Net:FTP.

Here's my code :
rules_controller.rb

```
def publish
   require 'net/ftp'
   ftp = Net::FTP.new('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')
   ftp.chdir('www/lol')
   ftp.putbinaryfile('rules.json')
   ftp.close
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never worked on this but looking at [ http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/classes/Net/FTP.html ] It seems `ftp.login` part is missing.

Well, if you dont need to be authenticated, then need some more insight to give any suggestion. Can you post the problem that you are facing exactly?

---

**Edit:**

If you can have your json data (containing all the rules) in a file(like you said `rules.json`), this `net/ftp` should work. Now if you are facing problem with saving the json content in a temporary file, this post - " [File.open, write and save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009031/file-open-write-and-save) " might help. But if you feel that the problem lies completely in `net/ftp`, then a error log or more detail description of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The login is not a problem, it seems we can avoid ftp.login by using FTP.new('host', 'login', 'pw')

Like I said, I want to upload a JSON with all my "Rules" on my FTP. I tried to put them on a variable but of course it doesn't work with "putbinaryfile" so I tried to use the Index action of my Controller Rules who has already a JSON render but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I missed the `login` part of `new` method. However, Ive updated my answer with something more. Let me know if it could help or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seems that it works with a "temporary" file before FTP upload :)