# How to call action on onclick-javascript in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to perform an action do file in controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:

```
def fileopen
        my_file = File.new("public/CHNAME1.txt","w") 
        my_file.write "\tfasf"
        my_file.close

    end
```

(it work well when i define it in helper and call it in view.)

in myview.html.erb, i want some thing like `<button id="button" onclick="readfile()" />`
How can I do that? 
I tried in application.js

```
function readfile() {
  alert('readfile work')
  $.ajax({
  alert('ajax work')
      url: "/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      ##don't know what to do to make fileopen work 
      }
  });
}
```

routes.rb

```
 match '/fileopen', to:'static_pages#fileopen', via: 'get'
```

and it's seem nothing happen. Only the first alert work.

Comment: Have you done trying with JQuery? I think that was really help my development time, and much easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question directly, you have to be able to handle the JS request in the controller. This is typically done by using the [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) block in Rails, like this:

```
def fileopen
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
            my_file = File.new("public/CHNAME1.txt","w") 
            my_file.write "\tfasf"
            my_file.close
        }
    end
end
```

This code may give you some sort of a response with your current code, but it might be the case that you need to appreciate better how [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) & Rails work in order to help you better

---

**How Ajax Works**

Ajax is a javascript technology which sends an "asynchronous" request to other pages on your website. By their nature, asynchronous requests are done completely independently of your main HTTP request, and basically act like a "pseudo" browser -- working in the background

Ajax is used to pull data from JS-enabled [endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint) (which are handled with the `respond_to` function in Rails, which you can then use to modify your page in some way. A lot of people get confused with Ajax, but it's actually quite simple -- it's just javascript which pulls data from another page, allowing you to manipulate your page with that data

---

**Using Ajax In Your Views**

The reason why this is important for you is because you mentioned you didn't know what to do with the `success` callback of your app. Hopefully my explanation will show you that the success part of the `$.ajax` call should be used to append the data you receive from the controller on your page

This can be done in this way:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "/static_pages/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      data: {name: $(this).val()},
      success: function (data) { 
          // append data to your page
          $("page_element").html(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank for your help, but in $("#button").click(function() , i just want when I click that button, fileopen will perform ( write to a text file), can you correct my code in '$("#button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "/static_pages/fileopen",
      type: "POST",
      data: {name: $(this).val()},
      success: function (data) { 
          // append data to your page
          $("page_element").html(data);
      }
  });
});'

Comment: I want fileopen active when have event onclick button, fileopen will write text to my file.

Comment: So you want to click button - write text to file - js will load text file & show?

Comment: no, I don't need load text file & show, I just want that I click button - write text to file.

Comment: So you don't need it to show on the page? You literally just want to write the text file?

Comment: Okay, you don't need to worry about your ajax `success` return for that. The real problem will be with the Rails backend (what happens in the controller). I don't have much experience with writing text files directly from the controller, but it seems these guys do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009031/file-open-write-and-save

Comment: You may wish to try this in your controller (replace your current code):

`directory = "../public"
File.open(File.join(directory, 'CHNAME1.txt'), 'w') do |f|
  f.puts "\tfasf"
end`

Comment: oh no, my def : fileopen , is correct, I can write to file when I just call it <%fileopen%>, but what I want is : it only write when I click button. :)

Comment: Okay, so you say that it works when you call `<% fileopen %>` - where do you put this in order for it to work? In a view?

Comment: yes, when I put in a view it works, but i don't know how to make it work when I do : < button> id="buttn" onclick= " javascript to call fileopen " </buton>, I don't know how to write code of "javascript to call fileopen"

Comment: You'd have to call `fileopen` using Ajax, and that would work as I explained. However, I am extremely confused at how putting `<% fileopen %>` in a view performed a controller action? Have you got a helper called `fileopen` somewhere?

Comment: Oh, you 're right, first, I put def fileopen in helper to make sure that it work, then I put def fileopen in controller to call it by AJAX. But i can't call it by AJAX, I tried code that you write above but it still not work.

Comment: Okay, there are a number of potential reasons why it won't work. Firstly, calling a helper is much easier than calling a controller function via JS. The first question I have is - do you have a route set up for `/static_pages/fileopen` ?

Comment: Okay good -- is the route POST or GET? Secondly, you have to look at whether the AJAX is firing. You should add an alert after the `.on('click')` event to see if it's actually calling the JS when it's being clicked. After that, we need to see if the Ajax is pinging the controller correctly

Comment: the route is GET, when alert befor AJAX, it work and alert after AJAX don't work

Comment: Okay, that means that the event is firing. Now what you need to do is test if Ajax is actually firing. To do this, in Chrome, right click on the page, select `inspect element` and then go to `Network` tab. Here, you'll see if the Ajax call is being made when you click the button. We need to know if another request is made when you click the button

Comment: Sorry, my network disconnected. Can you come back tomorrow and we will continue talking about this problem. Thank you so much for all your help I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sure! Just post a comment & I will talk

Comment: I edited the question, can you tell me what do I need to do next ?